# Как отследить нажатие закрытия окна

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qdialog, closeevent

Есть диалоговое окно. Как я могу отследить нажатие на его закрытие?

На данный момент при нажатии на крестик, происходит тоже самое, что и при нажатии на 'ок'.

После закрытия диалогового окна, которое я привёл, мне необходимо завершать выполнение ветки кода.

[image: img]

Вот код диалогового окна, в нём я переопределяю метод закрытия, как мне сделать, чтобы после нажатия оно закрывалось и код прерывался?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class DialogArchName(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DialogArchName, self).__init__(parent)
        self.namef = ''
        self.pathf = ''
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Введите имя архива:")
        self.namefield = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btnchoice = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбрать путь', clicked=self.getpath)
        self.rar_arch = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('.rar')
        self.zip_arch = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('.zip')
        btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Архивировать", clicked=self.getname)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(btnchoice, 3, 1, 1, 1)  # высота, право
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.namefield, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rar_arch, 0, 2, 3, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.zip_arch, 1, 2, 3, 3)
        layout.addWidget(btnOk, 3, 2, 1, 1)

    def closeEvent(self, a0: QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent) -> None:
        QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent(self, a0)

    def getname(self):
        self.namef = self.namefield.text()
        self.hide()
        return self.namef

    def getpath(self):
        self.pathf = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        return self.pathf
```

Comment: Можно перекрыть метод closeEvent, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/25901bb0010a84893c34c2a2c11dfdc348885af3/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__ask_before_close.py#L22 Про метод: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent . Для диалогов, думаю нужно еще метод диалога вызвать, например: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#reject

Comment: Я не знаю о каком общем случаи вы говорите, но если вам действительно нужна помощь, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick обновил вопрос

Comment: Внутри вашего `closeEvent` вызовите базовый метод `QDialog.closeEvent(...)`   там знают как закрыть диалог

Comment: Сейчас вызывается переопределенный вами, а надо вызвать базовый, который все закроет без шума и пыли

Comment: @AlexanderChernin поправил код, если это то о чем Вы говорите, то в таком случае программа просто крашится

Comment: А параметры где? Передайте людям параметры, иначе они теряются и крашат все вокруг

Comment: @AlexanderChernin в случае с передачей параметров все то же самое, как и было изначально. Диалоговое окно закрывается и код дальше выполняется. Возможно, что я не точно сформулировал задачу, в случае с закрытием окна мне нужно прекратить выполнение кода, но я не понимаю, как отследить для этого закрытие окна

Comment: Код всего приложения?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136624/discussion-between-clark-devlin-and-alexander-chernin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю в чем у вас проблема, попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class DialogArchName(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DialogArchName, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.namef = ''
        self.pathf = ''
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Введите имя архива:")
        self.namefield = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btnchoice = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбрать путь', clicked=self.getpath)
        self.rar_arch = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('.rar')
        self.zip_arch = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('.zip')
        btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Архивировать", clicked=self.getname)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rar_arch, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.namefield, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.zip_arch, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        
        layout.addWidget(btnchoice, 3, 0, 1, 1)       # высота, право
        layout.addWidget(btnOk, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        
# ???    def closeEvent(self, a0: QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent) -> None:
# ???        QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent()
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            self, 
            'Информация',
            'Вы уверены, что хотите закрыть Dialog?',
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            # тут делайте что вам надо перед закрытием диалога
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


    def getname(self):
        self.namef = self.namefield.text()
# ???        self.hide()
# ???        return self.namef

    def getpath(self):
        self.pathf = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        
# ???        return self.pathf
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DialogArchName()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

Хотя вы плохо объяснили что вам надо сделать, но я понял вашу задачу так:

**main.py**

```
...
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, front.Ui_MainWindow):
...


# архивация 
    def arch(self):                                                # архивация
        dirfiles = []
        if self.pathFile == '':
            if self.directory == '':
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Ошибка', 'Выберите папку либо файл')
                return # +++
            else:
                path = Path(self.directory)
                dirfiles = [str(f.absolute()) for f in path.glob("**/*")]
        else:
            pass
  
        if dirfiles:
            self.dialogname.exec_()
            
            dialogname = self.dialogname.namef
            pathname = self.dialogname.pathf
            
            if dialogname:
                if pathname:
                    archive_name = pathname+'/'+dialogname
                else:
                    archive_name = dialogname
            else:
                if pathname:
                    archive_name = pathname + '/' + os.path.split(self.directory)[-1]
                else:
                    archive_name = os.path.split(self.directory)[-1]

# !!! +++
            if self.dialogname.close_forcibly:                             # !!! +++
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(                         # !!! +++
                    self,                                                  # !!! +++
                    'Ошибка',                                              # !!! +++
                    'Что-то пошло не так'                                  # !!! +++
                )                                                          # !!! +++
                return                                                     # !!! +++
            
            try:
                shutil.make_archive(archive_name, 'zip', path)
                #print(self.closeEvent(QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent))
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Успех', 'Архивирование успешно завершено')
            except Exception:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Ошибка', 'Что-то пошло не так')
 
        if self.pathFile:
            print(self.pathFile)
            self.dialogname.exec_()
            dialogname = self.dialogname.namef
            pathname = self.dialogname.pathf
            if dialogname:
                if pathname:
                    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(pathname+'/'+dialogname+'.zip', 'w')
                else:
                    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(dialogname + '.zip', 'w')
            else:
                if pathname:
                    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(pathname+'/'+os.path.split(self.pathFile[0])[-1] + '.zip', 'w')
                else:
                    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.split(self.pathFile[0])[-1] + '.zip', 'w')
            try:
                for i in self.pathFile:
                    try:
                        archive.write(i, arcname=os.path.split(i)[-1], compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                    except Exception:
                        print(traceback.format_exc())
            except Exception:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Ошибка', 'Что-то пошло не так')
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Успех', 'Архивирование успешно завершено')
            archive.close()
 
...
```

**front.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt
 
 
class Ui_MainWindow():
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 250)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 230))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 230))
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 221, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 185, 221, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        self.browseArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browseArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 0, 221, 23))
        self.browseArch.setObjectName("browseArch")
        self.exlist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.exlist.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 221, 151))
        self.exlist.setObjectName("exlist")
        self.exButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 185, 221, 23))
        self.exButton.setObjectName("exButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Archivator"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать..."))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
        self.browseArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать архив"))
        self.exButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Извлечь"))
 
 
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):                                                   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
 
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Выберите:")
        self.rbDir = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Папку', self)
        self.rbPath = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Файлы', self)
        btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok", clicked=self.hide)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.rbDir, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rbPath, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btnOk, 3, 2, 1, 1)
 
 
class DialogArchName(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DialogArchName, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.namef = ''
        self.pathf = ''
# +++
        self.close_forcibly = False                                             # +++
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Введите имя архива:")
        self.namefield = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btnchoice = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбрать путь', clicked=self.getpath)
        self.rar_arch = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('.rar')
        self.zip_arch = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('.zip')
        btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Архивировать", clicked=self.getname)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(btnchoice, 3, 1, 1, 1)  # высота, право
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.namefield, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rar_arch, 0, 2, 3, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.zip_arch, 1, 2, 3, 3)
        layout.addWidget(btnOk, 3, 2, 1, 1)
 
    def closeEvent(self, a0: QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent) -> None:
# ???        QtWidgets.QDialog.closeEvent(self, a0)
# +++
        self.close_forcibly = True                                    # +++
 
    def getname(self):
        self.namef = self.namefield.text()
# +++
        self.close_forcibly = False                                   # +++
        
        self.hide()                           
  
# ???        return self.namef
 
    def getpath(self):
        self.pathf = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
# ???        return self.pathf
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как подсказали в обсуждении, судя по всему, мне нужно  то, что возвращает функция `QDialog.exec()`, дабы отследить нажат ли крестик, ведь вызвать функцию `closeEvent`, которую вы написали в другом файле я не смогу

Comment: @ClarkDevlin  `closeEvent()` напрямую вызывать не надо. Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы, вы должны предоставить минимально-воспроизводимый пример и хорошо рассказать что вы хотите сделать. О каком другом файле вы говорите? И что вы понимаете под выражением: "... это общий случай" ?

Comment: В обсуждении я предоставил полный код программы, там два файла. Мне нужно, чтобы после закрытия диалогового окна дальнейшая ветвь кода не выполнялась, в обсуждении это 75 строчка, в 1ом файле

Comment: @ClarkDevlin sorry, я не принимал участие в обсуждении. Если вам действительно нужна помощь, исправьте свой вопрос и предоставьте необходимую информацию и пояснения.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, кода много, так что по ссылкам

Comment: @ClarkDevlin я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.